# How to pause on network/syntax JS errors in chrome

Tags: javascript, debugging, error-handling, google-chrome-devtools, developer-tools

I have enabled [Pause on caught/uncaught exceptions in chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d3tVD.png) however when we get a 404() error the debugger doesn't pause.

For e.g. click 'Throw 404' button in below url and see that debugger doesn't pause.

https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/get-started#browser

Further it also doesn't pause on a syntax error.

How can I cause debugger to pause on any error what so ever

Comment: I have tried the following snippet but even that doesn't help here

--- window.onerror = function(){debugger;}

Comment: In devtools `Sources` panel, look at the sidebar on the right: https://puu.sh/zJqxT/7adb3f3e09.png

Comment: @wOxxOm, it doesn't help, please check with e.g. https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/get-started#browser